# Which of these men is her husband?

Tags: visual

Which of these men is her husband?

[image]

I found this puzzle in the Reddit but I don't have any idea about the answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/terriblefacebookmemes/comments/9cw99e/which_of_these_men_is_her_husband/

I spent like 1 hour searching every where to find any clue but noway :-(

Comment: Its probably just a joke and there isn't any meaning to this image

Comment: Can someone find a better quality image?

Answer (score 3):

The quality in this image is awful, but

> The man in black seems to have a ring on his right hand.
>  Note that the woman has no ring on her left, so the image may be reversed.

Other answers I get from research:

> The man in green because the other two visible men are a priest and a policeman, which you'd expect to see in this situation, but the man in green has no special qualification so he must be related to her. This answer doesn't really explain the arm on the right.

and

> The arm with the rat because he's trying to scare her off the ledge and make her fall.It'd be classic "boomer humor" because apparently Baby Boomers hate their wives.

Answer (score 0):

> I think her husband is the one on the right, who graps the rat. It could be a joke, that he prefers the rat and not his wife.